# Django : Doesn't look like a module path

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django and Python, but not to programming. Using Visual Studion, I'm trying to follow this toturial :
http://showmedo.com/videotutorials/video?name=1100000&fromSeriesID=110

But as soon as I ad something to "TEMPLATE_LOADERS" either a static path or a cllculated path I get an error: "C:/aa/ doesn't look like a module path"

The folder C:\aa\  exist on the harddisk
And I'm realy lost.

Jens B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be modifying TEMPLATE_LOADERS at all. You should be using TEMPLATE_DIRS.

Comment: I'll try that and then I'll return. :)

Comment: Can you explain a bit more your answer?